# Normal approximation of tail probability in binomial distribution

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, st.statistics, probability-distributions

**My problem:** From the [Berry--Esseen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry-Esseen_theorem) I know, that $$\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|P(B_n \le x)-\Phi(x)|=O\left(\frac 1{\sqrt n}\right),$$ where $B_n$ has the standardized binomial distribution and $\Phi$ is the standard normal distribution function. I can prove this for $x\approx 0$ with [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) and in a way similar [to this proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem).

Unfortunately Stirling's approximation becomes worse the bigger $|x|$ is, so that I can only show that

$$\sup_{|x| \le c}|P(B_n \le x)-\Phi(x)|=O\left(\frac 1{\sqrt n}\right)$$ for a fixed $c > 0$.

**My question:** Is there a direct proof for $\sup_{|x| > c}|P(B_n \le x)-\Phi(x)|=O\left(\frac 1{\sqrt n}\right)$, based on Stirling's formula? How can I estimate the error of the difference in the tail probability of the binomial distribution to the normal distribution?

**Note:** [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev's_inequality) does not provide the right convergence speed. As zhoraster shows [in his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1438737/finding-an-error-estimation-for-the-de-moivre-laplace-theorem/1443489#1443489) to [Finding an error estimation for the De Moivre–Laplace theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1438737/finding-an-error-estimation-for-the-de-moivre-laplace-theorem), also [Chernoff's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound) does not provide the right convergence speed, too. That's why I am looking for another method. I also want to use more easy and direct approximations than [Stein's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stein's_method) which is used in the proof of the Berry--Esseen theorem.

I already asked this question on MSE (see [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1441327/normal-approximation-of-tail-probability-in-binomial-distribution)), but I haven't got an answer there (even after adding a bounty). That's why I want to ask this question here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The needed observation here is that, whereas the relative error of the Stirling approximation is worse for large $|x|$, it gets multiplied by a fast decreasing normal density function, and then the product gets integrated to produce the desired result. Here are the details.

Let $X$ be a binomial random variable with parameters $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $p\in(0,1)$, where $n\to\infty$ and $p$ is fixed. For any integer $k$, let 
$$z_k:=\frac{k-np}{\sqrt{npq}},\quad q:=1-p. 
$$
Let 
$$K:=\{k=0,\dots,n\colon|z_k|\le n^{1/4}\},$$
so that $k/n\to p$ uniformly over $k\in K$. 
Let 
$$\hat p:=k/n,\quad\hat q:=1-\hat p=(n-k)/n,$$
$$\epsilon:=\epsilon_k:=z_k/\sqrt n,\quad\lambda:=\sqrt{q/p}, 
$$
whence 
$$\frac{\hat p}{p}=1+\epsilon\lambda,\quad\frac{\hat q}{q}=1-\epsilon/\lambda.$$
Uniformly over $k\in K$ one has $k\sim np$ and $n-k\sim nq$, so that $\frac1k=O(\frac1n)$ and $\frac1{n-k}=O(\frac1n)$. 
Here and in what follows, the constant in $O(\cdot)$ depends only on $p$. So, by Stirling's formula, over all $k\in K$ 
$$P(X=k)=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} p^kq^{n-k}
=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi n\hat{p}\hat{q}}}\,\frac1R\,\Big(1+O\Big(\frac1n\Big)\Big)$$
$$
=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi npq}}\,\frac1R\,\Big(1+O\Big(|\epsilon|+\frac1n\Big)\Big)
=\frac\delta{\sqrt{2\pi}}\,e^{-nH}\Big(1+O\Big(|\epsilon|+\frac1n\Big)\Big)
$$
where
$$R:=\Big(\frac{\hat p}{p}\Big)^k \Big(\frac{\hat q}{q}\Big)^{n-k},  
$$
$$\delta:=\frac1{\sqrt{npq}},\quad H:=H_k:=\ln(R^{1/n})=\hat p\ln\frac{\hat p}p+\hat q\ln\frac{\hat q}q
:=p\psi(\epsilon\lambda)+q\psi(-\epsilon/\lambda),$$
$$\psi(s):=(1+s)\ln(1+s).
$$ 
Since $\psi(s)=s + s^2/2 +O(|s|^3)$ for $|s|\le1/2$ and 
$\frac{|z_k|^3}{\sqrt n}+|\epsilon|=\frac{|z_k|^3}{\sqrt n}+\frac{|z_k|}{\sqrt n}=O\big(\frac{|z_k|^3+1}{\sqrt n}\big)$, we find that
$$(1)\qquad P(X=k)=\delta\,\phi(z_k)\Big(1+O\Big(\frac{|z_k|^3}{\sqrt n}\Big)\Big)\Big(1+O\Big(|\epsilon|+\frac1n\Big)\Big)$$
$$
=\delta\,\phi(z_k)\Big(1+O\Big(\frac{|z_k|^3+1}{\sqrt n}\Big)\Big)  
$$
over all $k\in K$, 
where $\phi$ is the standard normal density. 
Next, 
for $u=O(n^{1/4})$ and $|h|\le\delta/2$, 
$$\frac{\phi(u+h)+\phi(u-h)}{2}=\phi(u)\cosh(hu)e^{-h^2/2}
=\phi(u)(1+O(h^2u^2+h^2))=\phi(u)\Big(1+O\Big(\frac1{\sqrt n}\Big)\Big). 
$$
So, for $k\in K$
$$\delta\,\phi(z_k)=\frac12\,\int_{-\delta/2}^{\delta/2}[\phi(z_k+h)+\phi(z_k-h)]\,dh\,\Big(1+O\Big(\frac1{\sqrt n}\Big)\Big)$$
$$
=\int_{z_k-\delta/2}^{z_k+\delta/2}\phi(z)\,dz\,\Big(1+O\Big(\frac1{\sqrt n}\Big)\Big). 
$$
Also, 
for any $k\in K$ and any $z\in[z_k-\delta/2,z_k+\delta/2]$ one has 
$|z_k|^3-|z|^3\le3\delta(|z_k|+\delta/2)^2=O(1)$, whence $|z_k|^3/\sqrt n=O((|z|^3+1)/\sqrt n)$. 
So, by $(1)$, for some positive real $c$ depending only on $p$ and for all $k\in K$ 
$${J_k\!}^-\le P(X=k)\le J_k^+,$$
where
$$J_k^\pm:=\int_{z_k-\delta/2}^{z_k+\delta/2}\phi(z)
\Big(1\pm\frac{c(|z|^3+1)}{\sqrt n}\Big)\,dz.  
$$
Hence, for any $x\in[0,n^{1/4}]$, letting $K_x:=\{k\in\mathbb{Z}\colon0<z_k\le x\}$, one has 
$$P(0<B_n\le x)=\sum_{k\in K_x}P(X=k)
\le\sum_{k\in K_x}J_k^+$$
$$
\le\int_{-\delta/2}^{x+\delta/2}\phi(z)\Big(1+\frac{c(|z|^3+1)}{\sqrt n}\Big)\,dz$$
$$
\le\int_0^x\phi(z)\,dz+A\delta+\frac B{\sqrt n}
\le\int_0^x\phi(z)\,dz+\frac C{\sqrt n}, 
$$ 
where $A,B,C$ depend only on $p$. Quite similarly one obtains the corresponding lower bound on $P(0<B_n\le x)$, so that 
$$(2)\qquad |P(0<B_n\le x)-(\Phi(x)-1/2)|\le\frac C{\sqrt n}  
$$
for $x\in[0,n^{1/4}]$, where $\Phi$ is the standard normal cumulative distribution function.

On the other hand, for real $x>n^{1/4}$ one has $1-\Phi(x)=O(1/\sqrt n)$ and, 
by Bernstein's inequality, 
$$P(B_n>x)\le\exp\Big(-\frac{x^2}{2+x/\sqrt{npq}}\Big)
\le e^{-x^2/4}+e^{-x\sqrt{npq}/2}=O(1/\sqrt n). 
$$

It follows that $(2)$ holds for all real $x\ge0$ (perhaps with a greater constant $C$). Similarly, $|P(B_n\le0)-1/2)|\le\frac C{\sqrt n}$. 
Thus, for all real $x$
$$|P(B_n\le x)-\Phi(x)|\le\frac{2C}{\sqrt n},   
$$
as desired.

Comment: I have added details on the use of Stirling's formula and filled the gap on the estimation of $2\pi n\hat{p}\hat{q}$ by $2\pi np q$.

Comment: In the beginning of the answer, I have inserted a brief description of the main idea used in the proof.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your proof! It helped me a lot to find a good proof for my thesis (and I am sorry for my late response). I would like to cite your answer in my master thesis. Therefore I have the following question: You have found the proof by yourself, right? Shall I cite also someone else?

Comment: I am glad this proof has been helpful. I have not seen it elsewhere, even though the few tools used here are quite common: Stirling's formula, Taylor's expansion, summation via integration, Bernstein's inequality, and a few elementary estimates.